# Ignore records while doing LIKE

Tags: mysql, select

I've ran across a problem where I'm searching the database by a `LIKE` query:

```
SELECT description,
       title,
       hidden
FROM paragraphs
WHERE description LIKE '%some search%'
OR title LIKE '%some search%'
AND hidden = 0
```

Even when it searches, it should *completely* ignore records if `hidden` has a value of `1` in it, because I get returned hidden results.

How do you make a query that checks if `hidden` is `0` while if it's `1` the query should skip it those records.

Comment: Wow, how many answers :)

Comment: Now I have so many to choose from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the like's in brackets.

```
SELECT description,
       title,
       hidden
FROM paragraphs
WHERE (description LIKE '%some search%' OR title LIKE '%some search%')
AND hidden = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re write ur query with parentheses

```
SELECT description,
       title,
       hidden
FROM paragraphs
WHERE 
  (description LIKE '%some search%' OR title LIKE '%some search%')
AND 
   hidden = 0
```

Now you it should work

Answer (score 1):

Your query's criteria section is ambiguous, and that's likely causing your issues. Group your criteria with parenthesis as appropriate. Here's what I think you want:

```
SELECT description,
       title,
       hidden
FROM paragraphs
WHERE 
    ( description LIKE '%some search%' OR title LIKE '%some search%')
AND ( hidden = 0 )
```

*(Show me all items that match either this string or that string, AND aren't hidden)*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT description,
       title,
       hidden
FROM paragraphs
WHERE (
 description LIKE '%some search%'
 OR title LIKE '%some search%'
) AND hidden = 0
```